# ¿Cómo cambiar el color del prompt en csh?

Tags: unix, csh

Debo cambiar el color de mi prompt en csh.

Utilizo :

```
 set prompt = "\n%{\033[31m%}%m %n %{\033[0m%}>"
```

Pero no funciona. ¿Cómo hacerlo?

Comment: Si te funcionó la solución, ¿podrías aceptar la respuesta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este código me funcionó para ponerlo de color rojo:

```
export PS1="\e[0;31m[\u@\h \W]\$ \e[m"
```

para dejarlo como un cambio definitivo puedes agregarlo en el archivo `$HOME/.bash_profile` o en `$HOME/.bashrc`.

Básicamente:

- `\e[` Comienza la definición del prompt.
- `x;y` es el par asociado al color
- `$PS1` la variable que se utiliza para definir el prompt de las shell
- `\e[m` Cierra la definición del prompt.

Códigos de colores:

> Negro 0;30 
>  Rojo  0;31 
> Verde  0;32 
> Marrón 0;33 
> Azul   0;34 
> Morado 0;35
>   
> Cyan  0;36

Si reemplazas el 0, por 1, obtendrás el mismo color pero un poco más claro